# How to implement SUM(), DAY(), MONTH() and YEAR() from MySQL to ROOM

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have this code in SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(number), DAY(date) FROM conting GROUP BY DAY(date) ORDER BY DAY(date) ASC
```

then I need to convert in room:

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(number), DAY(date) FROM Records GROUP BY DAY(date) ORDER BY DAY(date) ASC") fun getResumeData(): List<Graph>
```

Graph.kt

```
data class Graph (
    @ColumnInfo(name = "DAY(date)") var index: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "SUM(number)") var value: Int
)
```

but it returns the error `no such function: DAY` how can I fix it?
note:

[image: this is my sql database]

[image: this is my sql query result]

Comment: Could you give more information regarding what data you are handling and also, the data you wish to retrieve?

Comment: sory for the late answer, i have edit my question to more simple data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android (and Room) uses SQLite, not MySQL, so you will need to structure your queries with functions that SQLite has available. You can do something similar with SQLite's `date()` and `datetime()` functions, see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html for more information.